# iOS create two static libraries with method in one library invoke method in another library

Tags: ios, static-libraries

Recently, I have seen a case: I downloaded two static libraries, called **lib1 and lib2.** I only imported **lib1** to my project, and its associate .h file, and invoke a method in this .h file. But when I build my project, the compiler told me that I must import **lib2** too.

**My question is:** If I create libraries myself, how can I reach the same thing? In my opinion, if **lib1** depends on **lib2**, and if the method in **lib1** invokes methods in **lib2**, the **lib1** itself must import **lib2**, doesn't it?

Any advice can be a great help, thanks sincerely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **lib1** depend on **lib2**

say for an example  **lib2 has 2 classes** in it out of which you need to use one class. **Just add only the interface reference**(Only the .h) not the whole library.

Reason behind when you build a library you are just compiling not running the app. So when the  time of compilation. compiler look for interface only not the implementation.At the time of your application compilation **both lib1 and lib2 need to be added.**

Comment: oh,yes,u are right! I had tried just #import lib2Class.h before I came here to ask the question, but the compiler builded failed and said cannot find lib2Class.h, I don't know why now I create a whole new library and then it build succeed...